# What is the request.auth data model input for writing Firebase security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I would like to read the documentation for the Firestore security rules `request.auth` input object model (all its properties and types and their purpose) in order to be able to use them meaningfully in my project's firebase security rules.

Unfortunately, all I could find are scraps of information in various unrelated contexts.

Do you know of centralized documentation for this vital firestore component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most complete documentation for the `request.auth` property in Firestore security rules is available here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.